# Disable gestures for table header view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uigesturerecognizer

I am trying to build similar controller to GMSPlacePicker.
I have Map View on background, then Table View with transparent header view. The problem is that all gestures (tap, pan) within header view are passed to table view. I wanna disable them, so all touches will go directly to map view.

I am able to do it If I set:

```
tableView.userInteractionEnabled = false
```

but now I am not able to scroll table view.

The question is how to disable all gesture only for header view, but keep getting them for table view.

Basically I wanna get the following behaviour: https://youtu.be/iSBbEZXDyGg

Comment: you think that the map should be behind the header view. but, it for sure will not work that way. this should be achieved in another way. for sure the map should be inside the header view. I am thinking of a way for that and I will get back to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick was to create subclass of UITableView and override

```
func hitTest(point: CGPoint, withEvent event: UIEvent?) -> UIView?
```

ANTableView.swift

```
import UIKit

class ANTableView: UITableView
{
    override func hitTest(point: CGPoint, withEvent event: UIEvent?) -> UIView?
    {
        let headerViewFrame = tableHeaderView!.convertRect(tableHeaderView!.frame, toView: self)

        if CGRectContainsPoint(headerViewFrame, point) {
            return nil
        }

        return self
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put your map inside the header view. Not behind it.

Comment: I've attached video of the example. You can see that there are should be way to add map behind header view.